# How to make the class active only for the pages that are open

Tags: php

Here is my pages

```
index.php
blog.php
contact.php
```

I am using the common file.

Here is my problem

I want to show the `class='active'` only the pages that are open how can i do that

```
<a href='index.php' class='active'>Home</a>
<a href='blog.php' class='active'>Blog</a>
<a href='contact.php' class='active'>Contact</a>
```

If i show the `class='active'` for all pages it is not the correct but how can it show it for only the pages that is currently opened by identifying it by url

My url will be something like this

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.php
www.mywebsite.com/blog.php
www.mywebsite.com/contact.php
```

Note :

I am not using any framework i am just using core php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the following steps

1. Identifying the url

   `http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`
2. Exploding with `/` for getting the page name
3. Taking the extension i.e., `.php` by using `substr`
4. And putting it the remaining with the condition

So,

```
$Url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$Exploded = explode('/', $Url);
$LastPart = end($Exploded);
$ExactName = substr($LastPart, 0, -4);
```

And you will get the $ExactName as `index` or `blog` or `contact`.

So, from here you can make the conditions to display the `class='active'` as you required.

**Condition :**

I have done it simply altogether as `$Page`

```
$Page = substr(end(explode('/', "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]")), 0, -4);
$Class = 'class="active"';
<a href="index.php"<?php if($Page=='index' || $Page==''){ echo $Class; } ?> >Home</a></li>
<a href="about.php" <?php if($Page=='about'){ echo $Class; } ?>>About</a>
<a href="contact.php" <?php if($Page=='contact'){ echo $Class; } ?>>Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: thanks, how can i make the conditions to display the class='active' for each items, help plz